# How can I move a Tkinter-Label relative to it's old position?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

So I wan't to move a `Label` (I can't use a `Canvas`, since I am showing a picture) relative to it's old position.

I tried to just use `bg.place(y-1)` but Python told me, that it doesn't know `y`.
I tried to get the coordinates of the label, but python told me that `Label`s don't have that attribute.

```py
from tkinter import *
import keyboard
w=Tk()
bg=Label(w,image=MYPICTURE)
bg.place(x=0,y=0,width=900,height=700)
def backgroundmovement():
    if ingame == True:
        yold=bg.coords(y)
        bg.place(y=yold-1)

keyboard.add_hotkey('w', lambda: backgroundmovement())
```

Comment: You should be able to call `bg.place_info()` to get a dictionary of all the options used by the widget (like `x` and `y`).

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use a canvas, and an image on the canvas, instead of a `Label`, the `place` geometry manager, and an image on the label...

Something like this:
-> a rectangle replaces the image, but you can easily replace that.
-> I recommend to use `import tkinter as tk` to avoid cluttering the namespace.
-> Using `keyboard` is not necessary, you can use `tkinter` events generated by the bindings of keys instead, and a `tkinter mainloop`.

```
import tkinter as tk


dxdy = {'Up': (0, -1), 'Down': (0, 1), 'Left': (-1, 0), 'Right': (1, 0)}

def backgroundmovement(e):
    try:
        dx, dy = dxdy[e.keysym]
    except KeyError:
        pass
    else:
        canvas.move(gif1, dx, dy)

window = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(window)
canvas.pack()

# gif1 = PhotoImage(file='my_beautiful_background.gif')
# canvas.create_image(50, 10, image=gif1, anchor=NW)

gif1 = canvas.create_rectangle(50, 50, 100, 100, fill='')

window.bind('<Up>', backgroundmovement)
window.bind('<Down>', backgroundmovement)
window.bind('<Left>', backgroundmovement)
window.bind('<Right>', backgroundmovement)

window.mainloop()
```